# Python Gtk TextView insert text at end

Tags: python, textview, gtk, gtk-textbuffer

I want to insert text to a textbuffer at the end...
Im using this: `gtk.TextBuffer.insert_at_cursor`

But if I clicking into the text there the new appears at the cursor...

How can i add text at the end?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using [`gtk.TextBuffer.insert()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextbuffer.html#method-gtktextbuffer--insert) with [`gtk.TextBuffer.get_end_iter()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextbuffer.html#method-gtktextbuffer--get-end-iter). Example:

```
# text_buffer is a gtk.TextBuffer
end_iter = text_buffer.get_end_iter()
text_buffer.insert(end_iter, "The text to insert at the end")
```

NOTE: Once you insert into `text_buffer`, `end_iter` is invalidated so make sure to get a new reference to the end-iterator whenever you want to append to the end of the buffer.